# Two CABasicAnimations inside of a group animation issue

Tags: ios, swift, cabasicanimation

I am trying to animate something to the below effect:

https://dribbble.com/shots/10885801-Tab-Bar-Simple-Animation

My below code produces something close to what I'm looking for, however once the animation group completes a solid line is drawn between the two specified points, instead of the layer just ending after the second animation.

```
        let start = fromTab.convert(fromLineView.center, to: backgroundView)
        let end = toTab.convert(toLineView.center, to: backgroundView)

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: start)
        path.addLine(to: end)
        
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = ColorConstants.green.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 4
        shapeLayer.lineCap = .round
        
        backgroundView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        
        let startAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        startAnimation.duration = 1
        startAnimation.fromValue = 0
        startAnimation.toValue = 1
        
        let endAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeStart")
        endAnimation.beginTime = startAnimation.duration
        endAnimation.duration = 1
        endAnimation.fromValue = 0
        endAnimation.toValue = 1

        let animation = CAAnimationGroup()
        animation.animations = [startAnimation, endAnimation]
        animation.duration = startAnimation.duration + endAnimation.duration
        shapeLayer.add(animation, forKey: "lineAnimation")
```

Here's a video of current behavior (I've slowed down the animation to see what's happening):

[image]

Any suggestions on achieving my intended result would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shape layer’s “base state” is to have a line drawn.

You create an animation that animates `strokeStart` and `strokeEnd`, but after the animation ends, it is removed, and your layer returns to it’s base state. (With your line visible.)

Add code to set `strokeEnd` to 0 before you submit your animations. That will set the “base state” to not showing a line, which is what you want.

### Edit:

(In order for the second animation in the animation group to work correctly, you’ll also have to do the below, as discussed in the comments. Moving it to the answer for clarity.)

Also add a third animation to your animation group that starts at the same time as your `endAnimation`, and for the same duration, that animates the strokeEnd value and has a fromValue and TwoValue both of 1. That will set strokeEnd to 1 for the entire duration of phase 2 of the animation (what you call the "endAnimation") so the line will be visible for phase 2.

Comment: (There is also a property called something like “removedOnCompletion” that you can set to false so that the animation stays in place after it ends, but that causes other problems and I don’t recommend it.)

Comment: hey duncan, thanks for the response. when i try setting the shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0, the endAnimation doesn't run. any other ideas?

Comment: Add a third animation to your animation group that starts at the same time as your end animation, and for the same duration, that animates the strokeEnd value and has a fromValue and TwoValue both of 1. That will set strokeEnd to 1 for the entire duration of phase 2 of the animation (what you call the "endAnimation") so the line will be visible for phase 2.

Comment: Another option would be to add a delegate to your animation group that implements `animationDidStop(_:finished:)`. In that method, remove the line (or set strokeEnd to 0.) That would cause the line to disappear at the end, but you might see the entire line flash onto the screen for a frame or 2 before it goes away.

Comment: Amazing, adding that third animation worked perfectly. Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: The thing to remember about `CAAnimations` on iOS is that they create a temporary animation layer (called a presentation layer) that covers the layer it’s animating. Once the animation is complete, the presentation layer is hidden

Comment: (Unless you take steps to tell the animation **not** to hide on completion by setting `isRemovedOnCompletion` to false. If you do that, though, the presentation layer covers the normal content layer, preventing the user from seeing changes to the content layer.)